# mysql search for category from serialized array

Tags: mysql

I have a table 'users_category'

```
'users_category' : id, prefix, name
```

and table 'users'

```
'users' : categories, etc...
```

where users.categories is an array of  users_category.id ids

User can be part of any category, if I stored the array of categories they are part of as a serialized array, how can I run a query to check if they are part of 'category x'

Ex:

```
SELECT users.*, users_category.* FROM 'users', 'users_category' WHERE users.categories='category x' AND users_category.id = 'category x'
```

I can't run a 'LIKE' command because the users.categories is serialized. Is their any way to search within the serialized data. Also I know that the above query may have errors

Comment: My suggestion is to *not* store serialized arrays in a MySQL database.  Look up something called "normalization" :-)

Comment: You have 2 of the 3 tables you need. As @RocketHazmat stated, you shouldn't have an array of categories in your users table. What you are calling "users_categories" should be called "categories" and then you SHOULD have a "users_categories" which contains user_id, category_id.

Answer (score 0):

Even though normalizing the table structure is a better way to move forward but if adopting that route is not optimal at this point then you may try this query:

```
SELECT u.*, uc.* 
FROM users u, users_category uc
WHERE uc.name='X' AND FIND_IN_SET(uc.id, u.categories)
```

It uses mysql function [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set).

Working demo available at: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7f392/3